# Deploy a web application with occasional multiprocessing needs

Tags: python, azure, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing, boto

I am building a web application that I want to host on a cloud service (either EC2 or Azure). The application is currently being built for a demo that will receive very little traffic ( < 1000 requests / day).

In general the application does not use much computing power, but has a few routines that make full use of my 12 core development environment using Python's multiprocessing library. I want results returned "online" within 60 seconds or less. I think that I would acheive better performance with more cores and would like to test into the 100s if possible. I expect in the 10s or these types of requests when the application is available as a demo each day.

My issue with cloud services is that if i provision a large instance, say 16 cores (an azure A9 or EC2 c4.4xlarge) it will cost me hundreds or thousands of dollars each month to keep available.

How can i deploy this application so that it is always available but only uses many, many cores when a user makes a request that requires them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question but in general you'd want to use some sort of autoscaling mechanism. (i.e AWS autoscale or your own).

60 Seconds is a very steep requirement for autoscaling instances, but you can get close to it by pre-baking everything into your EC2 AMIs from the get go. Meaning have all your application installed and components ready to go from the moment the EC2 instance completes bootup.  You can use something like [Packer](https://github.com/mitchellh/packer) or [aminator](https://github.com/Netflix/aminator)

For a 60 second turnaround time you would probably have to bring up several of them and perhaps load balance, then as soon as your computation is done you can tear them down.

You can even save more money by making use of EC2 spot instances. 
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/spot-instances/  The catch here is that spot instances are not guaranteed to be running so your application needs to be tolerant if Amazon decides to shutdown your instance.  Also, there's no guarantees if you bid for a spot instance that you will get it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps I could do this when a user logs into the application and terminate the instance when they log out or after a period of inactivity? Is boto a reasonable option in place of packer/animator? Sorry for my ignorance, I am very new to VMs

Comment: You can do either and you can do it with boto.  boto is just the python interface to AWS API, packer/animator or more about creating an AMI from scratch. Part of creating an AMI from scratch involves calling AWS APIs but there's another part that is installing all the packages needed by your application on the image/server. In your case it would be all your python dependencies, virtualenv, and what not with apache/nginx.